# How to use parameters in IN Clause sql informix

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, informix, parameterized-query

How to use parameters in IN Clause sql informix

```
StringBuilder cmdTxt = new StringBuilder();
cmdTxt.Append(" SELECT COUNT(emp_num) ");
cmdTxt.Append(" FROM tbl1 WHERE year IS NULL AND calc_year = ? AND camp IN (,,,)");


                using (var myIfxCmd = new IfxCommand(cmdTxt.ToString(), con))
                {
                    myIfxCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("calc_year", IfxType.Integer);

                    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                    }
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters[0].Value = calcYear;

                    res = int.Parse(myIfxCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
                }
```

I don't know how to handle passing parameters to `camp IN (,,,,)//Set of numbers`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've something like this

```
IDbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand(); //connection has been instantiated
cmd.CommandTimeout = connection.ConnectionTimeout;

var query = @"SELECT COUNT(emp_num)
              FROM tbl1 WHERE year IS NULL AND calc_year = @year AND camp IN ({0})";


cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@year", calcYear));
var sb = new StringBuilder();
//ids is a list/array of ids i want in the in clause
for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count; i++)
{
   sb.AppendFormat("@p{0},", i);
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p" + i, ids[i]));
}
if (sb.Length > 0) { sb.Length -= 1; }
string cmdText = string.Format(query, sb.ToString());

cmd.CommandText = cmdText;

cmd.Connection = connection;
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```